# ShapefileReader.readToGeometryRDD causes tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jts

When attempting to read an ESRI shapefile using the code below, I end up reaching the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.datasyslab.geospark.formatMapper.shapefileParser.ShapefileReader
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.{Coordinate, GeometryFactory, Point}

object GetRandomData {

  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {

    @transient val spark: SparkSession = {
      SparkSession
        .builder()
        .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
        .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
        .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb", "24")
        .appName("GetRandomData")
        .master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate()
    }
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    System.setProperty("geospark.global.charset", "utf8")

    val shapefileInputLocation = "~/Downloads/shapefile_folder/shapefile.shp"
    val spatialRDD = ShapefileReader.readToGeometryRDD(sc, shapefileInputLocation)
  }
}
```